# Hibernate Envers - fill audit tables on startup

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have written an application in Spring + Hibernate that uses Hibernate Envers to track history of business data.

On startup I have to load a lot of data from SQL scripts (not with Hibernate API!). Afterall I cannot see any data tracked in audit tables, probably because I did not use Hibernate API.

Do you know how can I fulfill audit tables with data created through SQL inserts? Is there any easy way to do it automatically? Can I do it with Hibernate Envers or any other technology that supports Envers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Envers does not presently have an automated way to audit records which were added or changed outside the scope of Hibernate.  However, you can have your import scripts insert the relevant rows into your Envers schema if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, it will be very annoying to keep up-to-date both types of SQL scripts to update business and history schemas.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to load the data via SQL scripts rather than pumping that information through Hibernate?  Doing so would certainly eliminate the need for dual scripts.